# Respond to HTTP request in plain text?

Tags: http, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

How do i do this in ColdFusion? The encoding has to be name=value fields that are separated by CRLF's. However, the issue is i don't know how i can tell that the page has been contacted and how to issue this kind of reply. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but for inspecting the incoming request check methods available from calling [getPageContext](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/getPageContext), for outgoing responses see [cfheader](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfheader) and/or [cfcontent](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfcontent) ?

Comment: Problem is, i never see the page at any point. Sagepay sends a POST request to retrieve the data but i never have a way of finding out where it went/what it accesssed. So stressful.

Comment: You can use cflog/writeLog for that, or even save the contents of a cfdump/writedump to a HTML file with a unique name to easily see complex stuff. Sagepay should be sending consistent requests so you can setup tests to mimic this.

Comment: I tried doing a database insert to test if the page was being hit, but it didn't log anything. I'm using the EXACT link i need to and nothing is happening. It's the first time i've implemented a payment gateway and i'm doing it all with no support/tutoring so to get as far as i have is an achievement but now i've hit a brick wall..

Comment: Logging is definitely the way to approach this - both writing your own messages (to check progress/etc) and also checking the CF logs for errors/etc - you need to confirm the request is being received and at what stage things stop happening, etc.

Comment: I don't know how to do this :/ I'll have a look into it, if you can find any resources for me to read through that would be big help.

Comment: Also double-check any assumptions you've made - stuff as simple as that you've given Sagepay the correct URL to call.

Comment: Not sure of any specific resources on doing logging, but there's a brief guide here: https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Logging+errors+with+the+cflog+tag

Comment: So if i use the code to log something into a file, any time that page is requested it should log something am i right? What happens if it is not going to this page even though the URL is definitely 100% correct, how do i even trace anything then?

Comment: You can add logging to Application.cfc/cfm to make sure it is hitting the application, also enable verbose logging at the web server level. You can also check tools like CF's Server Monitor (available through admin) or get the trial of Fusion Reactor to see incoming requests.

Comment: So can i just ask, if the file is being requested by Sagepay, if i set up code to create a file in a directory on my PC, it should do it, right?

Comment: If Sagepay requests `http://server.com/somefile.cfm` and the /somefile.cfm request is passed to CF and contains something like `<cfset FileWrite( "C:/tmp/#createUuid()#.html" , serializeJson(Form) )/>` and the user CF is running as has permissions to write to that directory, then yes.

Comment: Ok well i just tested a `<cffile action="write">` command which i know works as i tested it in a standalone document first, then put it into this document and it didn't work. So i know as much as it isn't accessing the file. I don't know why as the URL matches up 100% to what it should be..

Comment: Does the log get written to if you request the page yourself? Just like Sagepay is requesting the URL, you too can request the same URL to test things out.

Comment: If you have IIS or apache hosting ColdFusion, I'd look there first. Regardless of CF, that'll tell you if Sagepay is hitting your server.